# How to generate tex tboxes automatically if I have 3 radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `radio buttons`, when one of them is selected I want to automatically generate `textbox` . For example, If the user selected the 'Yes' `radio button`, I want the `textbox`, and if they select another radio 'No' button it will automatically generate `textbox` and then I want it to be clear 'yes' `textbox`. I tried..below is my code..

Can anyone help me??

```html
<html>
    <body>        
      <form name="radios">
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="H" onclick="show1();"/>yes 
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="L" onclick="show();"/>No 
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="LL" onclick="hide();"/>NA
        <TEXTAREA id="area" style="display: none;" NAME="data" ROWS=10 COLS=50></TEXTAREA>
        <TEXTAREA id="area1" style="display: none;" NAME="data" ROWS=10 COLS=50></TEXTAREA>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function show1() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block'; }
        function show() { document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'block'; }
        function hide() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none'; }
      </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: duplicate declaration of show() function

Comment: thanks for your answer..but my intension is when you select 'yes' then textbox is coming user has to enter manually in that...after when he click 'No' the yes textbox should be disappear and according to No textbox will come..Iam new to ask questions if anything wrong means sry..

Comment: @RaviKumar is there any real differences between `area` and `area1` ? any changes in the max length or any thing ? if there's nothing like this then why keep two `textarea` to achieve the same thing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my understanding below code will help you

```
function show() {
  document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'none';
}
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none';
}
function hide() {
  document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

See demo here https://jsbin.com/wogiyoxuhe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: if answer is correct then please mark it as accepted. See the stackoverflow tour -> http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Try this example [here](https://jsbin.com/dudaqu/2/edit?html,css,js,output).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Radio button</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="radios">
        <input type=radio name="x" value="h" onclick="show1();"/>Yes 
        <input type=radio name="x" value="l" onclick="show2();"/>No 
        <input type=radio name="x" value="ll" onclick="hide();"/>Null
        <textarea id="area1" style="display: none;" name="data" rows=10 cols=50>Area 1</textarea>
        <textarea id="area2" style="display: none;" name="data" rows=10 cols=50>Area 2</textarea>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('area2').style.display = 'none';
}
function show2() {
  document.getElementById('area2').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'none';
}
function hide() {
  document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('area2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Good luck!